# MySQL transpose columns to rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Project    | Q1_HC  | Q2_HC  | Q1_COST  | Q2_COST       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| ProjectA   | 20     | 15     | 20000.00 | 15000.00      |
| ProjectB   | 10     | 15     | 10000.00 | 15000.00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Out of this I want a view like this

```
-------------------------------------------
| Project    | Quarter| HC     | COST     |
-------------------------------------------
| ProjectA   | Q1     | 20     | 20000.00 |
| ProjectA   | Q2     | 15     | 15000.00 |
| ProjectB   | Q1     | 10     | 10000.00 |
| ProjectB   | Q2     | 15     | 15000.00 |
-------------------------------------------
```

I have seen lot of threads here but none helps me. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT Project, 'Q1' Quarter, Q1_HC HC, Q1_COST COST
FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT Project, 'Q2', Q2_HC, Q2_COST
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Project, Quarter
```